# Remove SKU Column from Transactional Emails

Tags: sku, transactional-mail

I would like to know how to remove the SKU column from transactional emails my store sends.

The email template contains `{{var order.shipping_description}}` but I don't know where this block is pulled from.

At least I assume that's what's rendering the table of info displayed in the following image:

[image]

Comment: You need to combine Tobias Zander's answer and MagePsycho's answer.
Tobias says to copy the files to your local theme, then you can edit them like MagePsycho says. It's bad practice to modify core files since they can be overwritten when you upgrade your Magento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit two files:
**File 1**:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml`
Find the following line and comment it:

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
```

**-----OR-----**

empty the value as:

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">&nsbp;</th>
```

**File 2**:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

And comment the following line:

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
```

**-----OR-----**

empty the value as:

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">&nbsp;</td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, i will check your solution and tell you soon....

Comment: i did as like your solution.

but some problem happened in css seems....

subtotal, shipping and handling and grand total need to move left....

what i have to do for this?

Comment: @user9434334345 will check and get back to you.

Comment: @user9434334345 habe a look at sales/order/totals.phtml (mentioned in my answer), that's related to the totals. But please DO NOT edit these files directly, these are code files and shouldn't be touched to remian upgradability. Either overwrite them in your own theme or define different  template files in the layout.xml.

Comment: thanks a lot @Tobias Zander, i will do this in themes files....

Comment: @MagePsycho, you can see the updated image.....

Comment: @user9434334345 Try to empty the <th> <td> values instead using '&nbsp;'? instead of removing them. should be an easy fix.

Comment: @MagePsycho i did as you told, but only sku name is displaying [delete 1 is sku name ].

can you please help me to remove it....

Comment: @user9434334345 Please find my edited answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: only hi, thanks its worked .see updated image . order email is fine. sku name is displaying in invoice and shipment email. please help me to remove heading "sku"....

Comment: Didn't you updated the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml file? also check if you have the file overriden in your custom theme

Answer (score 4):

So the directive

```
{{var order.shipping_description}}
```

is for the output of the shipping description (above of the order items list).

The order items list is usually generated by following directive:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

So to find out where this is defined you have to find the layout-handle sales_email_order_items, which is usually set in base/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

So the files you need to extend or overwrite in your custom theme are email/order/items.phtml for the headline and the defined item rendereres for the different type of product types.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, i will check your solution and tell you soon....