# Remove Sku Column from Transactional Email

Tags: magento-1.9, template, transactional-mail

I am trying to remove sku column from New order mail template. 
I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57805/remove-sku-column-from-transactional-emails). But there were still no changes in mail. I made changes in both base theme as well as in rwd theme which is by current theme. Any Ideas?

I have my cache disabled.
I did the same changes in rwd too.But no changes in my emails.

Comment: have you use any custom theme?

Comment: no, jst modified the rwd

Comment: yes i removed from default.phtml and as well as \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Check whether a custom e-mail template is configured in `System > Configuration > SALES > Sales Emails > Order > New Order Confirmation Template`.

If the value is different from `New Order (Default Template from Local)` it means that Magento is using a custom template defined in `System > Transactional Emails` and it may be the root cause of your issue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I have loaded the default mail template and just put some changes in the html and using it. But i haven't made any changes in {{layout..}} code. And since the layout  update handle is using the phtml files, I still don;t get why commenting the sku header column line is not making the sku column go away

Comment: Provided you refreshed/disabled the cache, the last explanation is that you are not changing the proper phtml file. Sorry I can't figure out how to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps:

**Step : 1** Open file at location `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml`

Find bellow code in above file

```
<p class="sku"><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>: <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
```

Now comment above code live this

```
<?php /*?><p class="sku"><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>: <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></p><?php */?>
```

Comment: I had already tried this.